# Can Windows Integrated Authentication be used to verify a $MachineName when initiated from a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-services, kerberos, windows-authentication, ntlm, network-service

I have a service account that communicates with a Web Service over HTTPS. I need to verify the calling machine name at the server, and deliver a response that includes this.

In my scenario, it's a security risk for the machine to specify its name in the request due to spoofing (e.g. `https://internal.com/GetSoftware?machine=host123`)

**Question**

1. Assuming that host123 is domain joined, how can a Windows Service pass along proof that it's domain-joined and prove that the machine name is indeed `host123`?

**Similar scenarios**

Scenarios like this are already in use in:

- AD DNS, where machines have permission to publish and update their records, albeit over a non HTTPS port.
- Integrated windows authentication to an IIS based webserver, a Microsoft specific challenge response is issued, and a browser like IE would step in and handle including the user token in the response.

I would like to make a similar connection that IE does with IIS for integrated authentication, but for the $machinename.

What approaches should I explore?

Comment: Some ideas may be Windows Remoting, SASL, WCF, Kerberos, etc.

Comment: Easiest approach would likely be running the service (or starting a child process) as NETWORK SERVICE and requesting a ticket to your web service as the machine. This will authenticate as the machine. You can either just include that ticket in the request and directly authenticate as the machine, or include it with a normal user auth ticket and valdiate seperately.

Comment: @Steve I've been in the OAuth, SAML, ADFS mindset for too long. Can you remind me where I can pick up the token in IIS? Is there an ASP.NET MVC object that obtains this credential?